# ionic - Adding a button inside a input field

Tags: css, ionic2, iconic

I'm trying to add a button inside an `<ion-input>` but wherever I add it inside the `<ion-list>` the button does not show on the screen.

What I'm trying to do is to show a button "Forgot" on top of the password field aligned to the right. Refer screen:

[image]

This is my HTML,

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list class="au-form" inset padding>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
            <button clear>Forgot</button>
        </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

How do I achieve this layout in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Fixed in the recent Ionic releases. Adding item-right on the button works.

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
 <button clear item-right>Forgot</button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 14):

For ionic 4 it will look a bit different:

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
 <button clear slot="end">Forgot</button>
</ion-item>
```

Instead of left and right they introduced start and end values, which make it easier to build interfaces for both left-to-right and right-to-left writing directions

Answer (score 3):

I have something similar, a disabled input with an enabled icon button next to the input.
Here is my HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>My Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input [disabled]="true" type="text" [(ngModel)]="MyModel"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button large clear (click)="doSomething()" item-end>
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
```

So in you case, this will work:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Your Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourModel"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button large (click)="doSomething()" item-end></button>
  </ion-item>
```

`item-left` and `item-right` directional properties are deprecated according to https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/rtl-support/

Comment: Can u please help me out. i tried the first code with floating label but the button lies above the input field.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Can you share your code? If you have an `ion-item` with an `ion-label`, `ion-input` and a `button (ion-button)` inside it, it should show up as expected. And remember the important attribute `item-end / item-right` on the `button`

Answer (score 1):

try using `flex`:

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list class="au-form" inset padding>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
           <div style="display:flex">
            <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
            <button clear>Forgot</button>
          </div>
        </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggling the password visible on and off is simple in ionic 4.

you have to mention the slot value as end (`slot="end"`) to make the icon at end along with `item-end` property

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="{{showPass ? 'text' : 'password'}}"></ion-input>
     <ion-icon item-end slot="end" name="{{showPass ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}}" (click)="showPass=!showPass"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

inside the component.ts file

```
showPass:boolean = false;
```